# Coupon Collector Problem with Batched Selections

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, coupon-collector

I am trying to solve a variation on the [coupon collector's problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem).

In this scenario, someone is selecting coupons at random with replacement from n different possible coupons. However, the person is not selecting coupons one at a time, but instead, in *batches*.

Here's an example problem formulation: There are 100 distinct coupons. A person makes selections in 10-coupon batches at random (each coupon with replacement). What is the expected number of batches necessary to have selected 80 unique coupons?

I have been able to determine the expected number of selections necessary to have selected k unique coupons when selecting one at a time (much like Henry's [answer to a similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/114636)), but I'm a bit stumped as to how to go about solving it with this particular wrinkle.

Any tips/guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

The probability not to have all $n$ coupons after drawing $k$ coupons is

$$
\def\stir#1#2{\left\{#1\atop#2\right\}}
P(K\gt k)=1-\frac{n!}{n^k}\stir kn
$$

(see e.g. [Probability distribution in the coupon collector's problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/379525)). Thus, if we draw in batches of $b$ coupons, the expected number of batches is

\begin{align}
\sum_{j=0}^\infty P(K\gt jb)
&=
\sum_{j=0}^\infty\left(1-\frac{n!}{n^{jb}}\stir{jb}n\right)
\\
&=
\sum_{j=0}^\infty\left(1-\frac1{n^{jb}}\sum_{l=0}^n(-1)^{n-l}\binom nll^{jb}\right)
\\
&=
\sum_{j=0}^\infty\sum_{l=0}^{n-1}(-1)^{n-l+1}\binom nl\left(\frac ln\right)^{jb}
\\
&=
\sum_{l=0}^{n-1}(-1)^{n-l+1}\binom nl\frac1{1-\left(\frac ln\right)^b}\;.
\end{align}

For instance, for $n=2$, this is

$$
\frac2{1-2^{-b}}-1=1+\frac2{2^b-1}\;.
$$

Comment: P.S.: [This duplicate question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1600817) links to a table with values for $1\le k\le n\le5$ from simulations, which coincide with the values given by the formula derived here.

Comment: Hi @joriki, I'm not so sure about this solution, it seems to clash with the answer you provided to [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1729848/coupon-collector-problem-with-groups?noredirect=1&lq=1). Both end up giving very different answers. Can you clarify this? Is one of them incorrect?

Comment: @ZackAshman: Those are quite different problems. In that other problem, the number of coupons per batch is variable; what's given instead is that each coupon has an (independent) probability $p$ to be in any given batch. I don't see why there should be any correspondence between the answers to the two questions.

Answer (score 3):

Let $N_t$ denote the number of different coupons after the selection of $t$ batches of size $b$ drawn from $n$ different coupons and $T_k=\inf\{t\geqslant0\mid N_t\geqslant k\}$  (here, $b=10$, $n=100$ and $k=80$). One is interested in 
$$
\mathrm E_{b,n}(T_k)=\sum\limits_{t\geqslant0}\mathrm P_{b,n}(T_k\gt t)=\sum\limits_{t\geqslant0}\mathrm P_{b,n}(N_t\lt k).
$$
The way to compute the value of $\mathrm E_{b,n}(T_k)$ is unclear, although the dynamics of $(N_t)_t$ is easy to describe.

To wit, $N_0=0$, $N_1=b$, and if $N_t=i$, $N_{t+1}=i+M_t$ where $0\leqslant M_t\leqslant b$ almost surely and the distribution of $M_t$ depends on $i$ and may be written down. For example, if $b=2$, $M_t=0$ with probability $\frac{i(i-1)}{n(n-1)}$,  $M_t=1$ with probability $\frac{2i(n-i)}{n(n-1)}$ and, finally, $M_t=2$ with probability $\frac{(n-i)(n-i-1)}{n(n-1)}$.
Thus, $\mathrm E_{2,n}(M_t\mid N_t)=2(1-N_t/n)$ and $\mathrm E_{2,n}(N_t)=n(1-(1-2/n)^t)$.

More generally, $\mathrm E_{b,n}(M_t\mid N_t)=b(1-N_t/n)$ and $\mathrm E_{b,n}(N_t)=n(1-(1-b/n)^t)$.

One might want to estimate $\mathrm E_{b,n}(T_k)$ by the root $t_{b,n}(k)$ of the equation $k=\mathrm E_{b,n}(N_t)$, that is,
$$
t_{b,n}(k)=\frac{\log(1-k/n)}{\log(1-b/n)},
$$
for example, $t_{10,100}(80)\approx15.28$. However, the quality of this approximation (or rather, the range of parameters $(n,b,k)$ where it is passable) should be checked, numerically or otherwise.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer. Let me clarify one specification of the problem: There could be duplicates in each batch. That is, $N_1\leqslant b$ as collisions are possible after the first selection.

The batch here acts only as a limit on how often one can check to see if the number of unique coupons selected has met or exceeded $k$.

Any thoughts on that?

Comment: After thinking about this with my comment above in mind, it seems like a good approximation would be taking the ceiling of the expected number of trials divided by batch size: $$ n \log_e \left(\frac{n}{n-p}\right) $$ divided by $b$. Thoughts?