# How to calculate the expected value of the coupon collector problem if we are collecting the coupons in groups of k?

Tags: probability, coupon-collector

The problem:

There are n different kinds of coupons, and we need to get every kind of coupon at least once to win. Each time we get new coupons we get them in a batch of k coupons where k ≤ n (the same coupon can appear multiple times in the batch of k coupons).

Let X<sub>k,n</sub> be a random variable that denotes the number of batches we need to buy to collect all the n different coupons.

I already know and understand how to calculate the expected value when k=1 (that is the classic coupon collector problem), but have difficulty calculating E[X<sub>k,n</sub>] for k > 1.

If it helps, I've also made some simulations and estimations, and came up with this table:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsKnJ.jpg]

Comment: Note that the formula derived in my answer to the duplicated question reproduces the numbers in your table.

Answer (score 0):

Let $k=2$.  Let $E(m)$ be the expected number of pairs needed to complete $n$ coupons when you already have $m$ coupons.
The chance of ending with $m+1$ coupons comes from three cases: First new, second old;First old, second new;Both the same new coupon.
$$E(m)=1+\frac{(n-m)(n-m-1)}{n^2}E(m+2)+\frac{2m(n-m)+(n-m)}{n^2}E(m+1)+\frac{m^2}{n^2}E(m)$$
Then you build the matrix to get numerical answers; or solve the algebra to get exact answers.
For example, $E(n-1)=1+\frac{(n-1)^2}{n^2}E(n-1)=\frac{n^2}{2n-1}$

Comment: If $n=4$ then $E(0)=4^2\left(\frac47−\frac6{12}+\frac4{15}−\frac1{16}\right)$, where the numerators come from Pascal's triangle and the denominators are $16−m^2$. I think that gives the general form for $X_{2,n}$

Comment: Is there a general formula for calculating T(m, i) where m is the number of coupons we already have (out of the n total coupons) and T is the probability of ending up with i coupons after drawing a batch of k coupons.