# YACCP: Coupon collector: Pull 20 coupons per time

Tags: probability, stochastic-calculus, coupon-collector

Yet-another-coupon-collector's-problem: 
**I know this may be a very similar question to others, but I couldn't crack it and this one has a *'special knack'* to it, please bear with me**:

1. 260 specific coupons are in the pool (will give you completely random coupons every time, not taking into account what it gave out already)
2. you pull 20 (random, but all different) coupons out per try *(this is the 'special knack')*
3. how many times do you have to pull until you pulled 100% of the coupons
4. (follow-up: how many times do you have to pull until you pulled ~95% )

(Complete flabbergastedness:

- How to input this problem in wolframalpha?
- How to calculate this using the browser console (vanilla javascript))

thanks, any help a lot appreciated

Comment: When you pull your $20$ random coupons out, is that with replacement?  Also, if you don't have to put the coupons back, you can get them all in just $13$ tries, so that's what I'd recommend.

Comment: replacement I guess means you get completely new coupons, from an unlimited pool. Then yes, that is the case, thanks, edited

Comment: So there are 260 specific coupons to collect and you have an unlimited supply of boxes right ? And the $20$ coupon in one box are chosen randomly, with possible replacement ?

Comment: Sorry, I shouldn't have joked and obscured the real question.  On a single try, when you choose $20$ coupons, are they all distinct coupons, or could you choose the same coupon several times?

Comment: Thanks guys, I made it more specific according to your suggestions, sorry for the unclear question

Comment: Downvote: Is this question too simplistic - in which case I don't get why someone just doesn't post the formula - or just still too unclear? This is not homework, and I did my research, went on Wikipedia/searched math.stackexchange.com, I just can't crack it and would appreciate help? At least some link to a good resource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/131664/coupon-collector-problem-with-batched-selections?rq=1) Formula for approximating this problem, I hope you guys agree:

$$\frac{log(1−x/260)}{log(1−20/260)}$$

(where t batches of size b drawn from n different coupons)

That would yield the following results:
for 247 (95%) different coupons: 37.45 times