# Cardinality of union of random sets

Tags: probability

Suppose I choose $k$ random $r$-sets from the universe $\{1, \dots, n \}$. Let
$A_1, \dots, A_k$ denote these sets.

Now let $A = A_1 \cup \dots \cup A_k$ and let $a = |A|$. Here, $a$ is a random variable; what is its distribution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Coupon Problem generalized, or Birthday problem backward.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114544/coupon-problem-generalized-or-birthday-problem-backward)

Answer (score 2):

The probability that some given element in the universe does not belong to any $A_i$ is $\left(1-\frac{r}n\right)^k$ because the sequence $(A_i)$ is i.i.d. hence
$$
E[a]=n-n\left(1-\frac{r}n\right)^k.
$$
Not sure the full distribution has some nice expression, except for very small values of $n$ and in some well-chosen large $n$ asymptotics.

Answer (score 0):

According to the paper ["Estimating The Size Of A Union Of Random Subsets Of Fixed Cardinality"](https://ems.press/content/serial-article-files/616), the distribution is:

$$
p(a) = \frac{{n \choose a}}{{n \choose r}^k} \sum_{i=0}^{a-r} (-1)^i {a \choose i} {a - i \choose r}^k
$$