# Inverse birthday estimation

Tags: probability, combinatorics, birthday

We all know the [birthday problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem).

Suppose an inversion* of the birthday problem: given a number of distinct birthdays (*c*) from a set of people, how can you estimate the number of people you had (*n*)? (given num birthdays < 365). And for arbitrary bin spaces other than 365 (*k*)?

E.g. you have *c*=47 days marked off in your school's calendar as birthdays (*k*=365), how big is your school most likely (*n*)?

Birthday collision problems are usually expressed as the odds of getting 1  or more collisions, I think we want the maximally likely *quantity* of collisions given *c* and *k* and add that to *c* to get a likely *n*.

*(* not sure if this is the right term or name for this question)*

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114544/coupon-problem-generalized-or-birthday-problem-backward?rq=1 ?

Comment: The idea you are asking for is called maximum likelihood estimation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say there are n people in your school, and k days in the year (so the normal birthday problem has k = 365).  Then the probability that any given day is not a birthday is $(1-1/k)^n$.  If $k$ is large then this is approximately $e^{-n/k}$.    Therefore we expect there to be $k e^{-n/k}$ days that are nobody's birthday.

So say we observe $j$ days which are somebody's birthday; then there are $k-j$ days which are nobody's birthday, and approximate number of people in the school can be found by solving $k - j = k e^{-n/k}$ for $n$.  This gives

$$n \approx -k \log \left(1-{j \over k}\right)$$

So in the case you've suggested with $j = 47, k = 365$ we get

$$ n \approx -365 \log (1 - 47/365) \approx 50 $$.

Comment: does this problem or formula have a name?

Comment: also, I'm assuming you're using natural log?

Comment: Yes, it's natural log.  I don't know a name for this problem, although that doesn't mean there isn't one.

Answer (score 1):

This type of *inversion* probably lies behind other applications that make use of the concept of [posterior probability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posterior_probability). The approach mentioned below has been used in other areas such as data mining.

Let $D$ be a random variable denoting the number of distinct birthdays. For a given number of birthdays $d$, the desired answer is the value of $i$ that maximizes $\Pr[n = i \vert D=d]$. Also note that by the [Bayes' theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem), 
$$\Pr[n = i \vert D=d] = \Pr[D=d \vert n = i]\cdot \frac{\Pr[n = i] }{\Pr[D=d]}$$
And we want to choose the value of $i$ that maximizes the above formula. Since $d$ is fixed, $\Pr[D=d]$ is fixed. Furthermore, unless we have some knowledge about the distribution of $n$, we assume that all the values are equally probable, i.e., $\Pr[n = i] $ is equal for all $i$. Then the problem reduces to finding the $i$ that maximizes $\Pr[D=d \vert n = i]$, which can be solved using the birthday problem. In case we have more knowledge about the distribution of $n$, we can substitute for $\Pr[n=i]$ in the above formula to apply this knowledge.